# Python Unit Testing Failure

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to capture the output of the command "wahji -h". Save that output into the string op. I have a text file saved as wahjiHelp.txt that is the exact expected output of the command "wahji -h". I then try to read this file into the string who2. I then try to compare the two strings which should be exactly the same by using an assertion to try to make sure i am receiving the correct output from my command "wahji -h".I am new to python programming and programming in general. I am using python 2.7. Help would be much appreciated!!!

When i run the test i get the following failure message: 
I can see that there is a difference between the two strings it is comparing. When i run "wahji -h" in the terminal the output starts with 'usage: wahji.py [-h]'. For some reason when i capture that output from that command and save it to the string op it displays the output as 'usage: wahji [-h]'. It does not add the .py extension and I do not understand why when i use the subprocess to capture the output of the command, why the output is not exactly the same as the output when i actually type the same "wahji -h" command into the terminal.

```
FAIL: test_help (__main__.HelpTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test_wahji_help.py", line 30, in test_help
self.assertEqual(op, who2)
AssertionError: 'usage: wahji [-h] {init,remove,page,build,new} ...\n\noptional arguments:\n  -h, --help            show this help message and exit\n\nwahji commands:\n              The following are possible command line parameters for wahji\n\n  {init,remove,page,build,new}\n                        \n                        \twahji init --help\n                        \twahji remove --help\n                        \twahji page --help\n                        \twahji build --help\n                        \twahji new --help\n' != 'usage: wahji.py [-h] {init,remove,page,build,new} ...\n\noptional arguments:\n  -h, --help            show this help message and exit\n\nwahji commands:\n              The following are possible command line parameters for wahji\n\n  {init,remove,page,build,new}\n                        \n                        \twahji init --help\n                        \twahji remove --help\n                        \twahji page --help\n                        \twahji build --help\n                        \twahji new --help\n'
```

Here is my code:

```
  1 import unittest
  2 import subprocess
  3 import filecmp
  4 import os
  5 import sys
  6 
  7 
  8 class HelpTest(unittest.TestCase):
  9 
 10         def test_help(self):   
 11 
 12                 op = subprocess.Popen(["wahji", "-h"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
 13 
 14                 print op
 15 
 16                 opw = open( 'op1.txt', 'w' )
 17                 opw.write(op)
 18                 opw.close()
 19 
 20                 who = open('wahjiHelp.txt', 'r')
 21                 who2 = who.read()
 22                 who.close()
 23                 print who2
 24 
 25                 # print filecmp.cmp('op1.txt', 'wahjiHelp.txt', shallow = False)
 26 
 27                 op.strip()
 28                 who2.strip()
 29 
 30                 self.assertEqual(op, who2)
 31 
 32                 
 33 
 34 
 35 if __name__ == '__main__':
 36         unittest.main()
```

Comment: The "usage" message is probably going to `stderr`, not `stdout`.

Comment: op = op.strip();  who2= who2.strip() ....declare op and who2 new, the result of the strip step

Comment: try to remove `\r` chars too (if you're running windows)

Comment: why is the output of running "wahji -h" different than when i capture the output of the command using a subprocess? When i enter "wahji -h" in terminal the start of the output is "usage: wahji.py". When I capture the output of that command using a subprocess and save it to a string the start of that output is "usage: wahji". See the difference? The second output is missing the .py extension after wahji. Why is this?